# Is "ramped return to work after physical injury" covered by Statutory Sick Leave (UK)

Tags: sickness, part-time, england

From the [UK gov website on Stat. Sick Pay](https://www.gov.uk/employers-sick-pay/entitlement):

> SSP is paid when the employee is sick for at least 4 days in a row (including non-working days).

If an employee was injured or ill in such a manner that they were fully signed off by a doctor for a month, and now they want to ramp their working-days-per-week back up over an extended period that goes beyond the sick leave policy of the company... then are they elligible for SSP, or any other kind of equivalent government support?

For SSP it seems like the answer is "no", based on that quote?
But it also sounds ... improbable ... that the system ignores such a plausible health need?

Comment: Discuss with Doctor, HR or government, choose wisely. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** - when doing a phased return to work any days they *aren't* working [are eligible for SSP](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/statutory-sick-pay-employee-fitness-to-work#back-to-work-action-plans).

> If you agree a phased return to work or altered hours after a period of sickness, pay SSP for the days that your employee is sick in the normal way. Any day for which SSP is paid will count towards the maximum entitlement of 28 weeks. Your employee’s absence must form a period of incapacity for work before SSP is paid.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I wish I could message all the people who (I assume) downvoted the question on the grounds that I had "already found the answer", to say "see ... THIS is why I asked :P" :D